# SSIS Derived column expression moving specific characters to the end of the string

Tags: ssis

In SSIS expression I am trying to move prefix number in brackets to the end of the string but haven't been successful. The data is not stored inside the variable, rather is just a simple phone column which needs to be replace with a new one that resembles the stated data below.
Example:

unicode string: (907) 222-1234 to look like this:

222-1234 (907)

How should the expression in Derived Column look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUBSTRING( YourVariable , 7, LEN(YourVariabl) -7+1 ) + " " + SUBSTRING( YourVariable  , 1,5 )
```

Comment: if your phone number follows the pattern "(***) space ***-****" strictly :)

Comment: hi @KrvoKrvetina, then just replace the `YourVariable` to `YourColumn`, should solve your problem xD

Comment: Resolved the issue using your answer, thank you a lot.

Comment: my pleause! @KrvoKrvetina